# laravel Error Exception Missing argument 2 for Controller::destroy()

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to call the destroy function in the controller passing in two parameters but I get the error: exception missing argument 2 for GradoController::destroy().

I have grades from 1 (first) through 6 (sixth) and each has subjects associated with it.  The grades are listed on the page in tabs and by clicking the tab you get a list of the subjects that go with the grade.  I put a delete button next to each subject so the user can click delete and detach the subject from the grade.

I am trying to pass both the gradeId and the subjectId to the destroy method in GradoController

My view file index.blade.php:

```
<html>
 <head>

 {{HTML::script('assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.js'); }}
 {{HTML::script('assets/js/jquery-ui.js');  }}
 {{HTML::script('assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js'); }}
 {{HTML::style('assets/css/jquery-ui.min.css'); }}

  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( '#tabs' ).tabs();
  });
  </script>
</head>


<body>
<h1>Lista Materias por Grado</h1>
<?php 
    $year = date("Y");
    $month = date("m"); 
    if($month < 8){
       $year = $year - 1;  
    } ?>
<h2>{{$year}}-{{$year+1}}</h2>

<div id="tabs">
<ul> <?php $i=1; ?>
   @foreach($grados as $grado)
    <li><a href="#tabs-{{$i}}">Grado:{{ $grado->name_grados}} </a></li>
    <?php $i++; ?>
   @endforeach
  </ul>
  <?php $i = 1; ?>
  @foreach($grados as $grado)
    <div id="tabs-{{$i}}" >
           @if($grado->subject->count())
             @foreach($grado->subject as $subject)
          <li> {{ $subject->name_subjects }} 


        {{Form::open(array('method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => array('grados.destroy', $grado->id_grados, $subject->id_subjects)))  }} 


            {{ Form::submit('Delete',array('class' => 'btn btn-danger')) }}
     </li> 
         @endforeach
           @else
            No hay materias asociadas
       @endif
             </br></br>
              {{ link_to_route('grados.edit', 'Agregar Materias',
 array($grado->id_grados), array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }} 
             <?php $i++; ?>
  </div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

My GradoController's destroy function:

```
public function destroy($gradoId, $subjectId)
{        

        $grado = Grado::find($gradoId);
        $year = 2014;        
        $grado->subject()->detach($subjectId, array('year_grado_subject'=>$year));


        return Redirect::route('grados.index');                 
}
```

In routes I have:

```
Route::get('grados/{id_grados}/{id_subjects}/destroy', 'GradoController@destroy');
Route::resource('grados', 'GradoController');
```

Thanks!

Comment: $subject->id_subjects is there a field in your database called id_subjects?  Or is it id_subject

Comment: Yes it's called id_subjects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can imagine is that the Form uses the action via

`Route::resource('grados', 'GradoController');`

and the "default DELETE" (see http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) only uses one parameter (/grados/{parameter}), so the second parameter gets lost and is not passed on to the Controller action. This is because there is no route set on

`Route::get('grados/{id_grados}/{id_subjects}/destroy','GradoController@destroy');`

AND it doesn't use Route::delete but rather Route::get.
So changing it to

`Route::delete('grados/{id_grados}/{id_subjects}/destroy',['as' => 'grados.destroy', 'uses' => 'GradoController@destroy']);`

will hopefully do the trick. Plus I would avoid defining the same routes twice. E.g. you can use this:

`Route::resource('grados', 'GradoController', array('except' => array('destroy')));`

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.  It looks like now it is finding the function with the parameters, since it redirects to: http://localhost/laravel/grados/{gradoId}/{subjectID}/destroy,  but now it gives me a MethodNotAllowedHttpException.  How might I fix that.

Comment: Ok, I changed the Route::get to Route::delete and it doesn't give the exception anymore, but now the subjects are deleted in sequential order by Id (lowest id first) no matter which delete button I press, but I suppose that's a question for another post.  Thanks for your suggestions, I'd been stuck for a long time and they've moved me forward!

Comment: Ah, right, it should be Route::delete, will update the answer